Algorithm for creating an esports season schedule
I run an esports league for my Boys & Girls Club and others that want to participate. I'm trying to find a way to take information about when different teams are available to compete and use that to create a season-long schedule (usually 6 weeks long).
Currently, I have 2 genetic algorithms that can do most of the work needed but there's always a lot of manual work at the end separating the games into weeks.
I currently format the data I'm working with like this:
  {
    "teamA": "Team A",
    "teamB": "Team B",
    "day": "monday",
    "time": "04:30"
  },

Genetic algorithm for creating balanced number of games (every team has the same number of matches against as many different teams as possible):
https://gist.github.com/jeremiahfallin/b6846e8a6e076b766f68379de64eb217
Genetic algorithm to break that set of games into different weeks:
https://gist.github.com/jeremiahfallin/437c159106007421c355e7395d9548fe
I've also tried the Misra Gries Edge Coloring Algorithm to put the matches into a week-by-week schedule. It works nicely but it almost always produces a schedule with 1 more week than there are number of games per team and I would prefer no bye weeks.
I feel like there has to be a better and more efficient way to handle this problem but I've struggled to find one. Any suggestions or learning material to improve this process is appreciated.

This sounds like an operations research type of problem.  Generally, one effective method for dealing with this kind of combinatorial optimization / scheduling problem is to formulate it as an instance of integer linear programming, and then apply an off-the-shelf ILP solver.
For instance, you might have zero-or-one variables $x_{t,u,d}$, with the meaning that $x_{t,u,d}=1$ if teams $t,u$ play each other on day (or day+time) $d$, or 0 otherwise.  Then your constraints can be expressed as linear inequalities on these variables.
